# Rattles with beads or necklace with beads?

Tags: combinatorics

I came across this problem in a book called *limits, sequences combinations* great book for intro to combinatorics .

> A rattle consists of a ring with $3$ white beads and $7$ red ones strung on it. Some rattles seemingly different can be made identical by arranging the rings and moving the beads in a suitable manner (rotation or flipping). Find the number of different rattles .

I of course thought polya enumeration on this one but was thinking it can be done case by case without being too messy . Can anyone help? Also this is essentially  the same problem as a necklace with $n$ beads, $k$ colors is it not ?

Comment: Yes, these rattles are necklaces in the symmetries that are allowed.  Most of the necklace problems I have seen do not specify the number of beads of each color, just the total number of beads and colors.

Comment: would it be as easy as taking 10 spaces,  choosing 3 of these for the white beads ? ( the red ones must go around them then )

Comment: but that would overcount? as In wwwbbbbbbb same by rotation as bbbbbbbwww

Comment: oops , I meant r not b ..same concept though

Comment: Yes, it would overcount.  That is the reasoning behind my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A hand count is not hard.  You have to find a way to organize it so you count each configuration only once.  We get one configuration for each weak partition of $7$ into $3$ parts.  We get
$$7,0,0\\6,1,0\\5,2,0\\5,1,1\\4,3,0\\4,2,1\\3,3,1\\3,2,2$$ for eight possibilities.  Clearly these are all distinct.  You need to convince yourself that there are not two configurations for a partition, but rotation and flipping give six configurations, which matches the number of orders of a partition.

Comment: why are we talking partitions when it's combinations?

Comment: Because you just count the red beads between each pair of whites.  This gives the partitions.  As I said, you have to convince yourself that any arrangement of $5,2,0$, say, can reach any other by rotation and reflection.

Comment: pair of whites? there are 3 not 4

Comment: do u have any links that are similar problems to this?

Comment: There are three white beads.  I am talking about the number of reds in each interval, so there are three pairs of whites.  One of the $5,2,0$ configurations is wwrrwrrrrr for example.

Comment: what is that called? links please

Comment: and now i DO get your idea. but am wondering what it's called ? weak partitions? and is it 3 parts because of 3 whites? if 4 whites we would then be placing white beads in between the reds which also give a ' weak partition ' into 4 parts

Comment: They are weak partitions because we allow $0$.  Yes, if there were $4$ whites we would have partitions into $4$ parts.  With $4$, though, partitions are not enough.  If there are four whites and ten reds the reds can be $1,2,3,4$ around the circle or $1,3,2,4$ giving distinct rattles.  There are $4!=24$ orders of four things and rotations/reflections can only get us to $8$.  There must be three distinct rattles here, and $1,4,2,3$ is the other one.

Comment: u mean the whites can be 1,2,3,4.. typo?

Comment: No, I meant $1,2,3,4$ to suggest $wrwrrwrrrwrrrr$ so the numbers show the number of reds in each group.

Comment: ah you are taking the 'lesser of the two evils '

Comment: or the lesser of the two numbers of beads..right?

Answer (score 0):

Let me just observe that with $(3,10) = 1$ and $(7,10) = 1$ Polya will
be  very simple  in  this  case. The  OEIS  uses  necklace for  cyclic
symmetry and  bracelet for dihedral, so  we have a bracelet  here. The
cycle index is from first principles

$$Z(D_{10}) = \frac{1}{20} \sum_{d|10} \varphi(d) a_d^{10/d}
+ \frac{1}{4} a_2^5 + \frac{1}{4} a_1^2 a_2^4.$$

With the two colors our answer is given by

$$[W^3 R^7] \frac{1}{20} \sum_{d|10} \varphi(d) (W^d+R^d)^{10/d}
\\ + [W^3 R^7] \frac{1}{4} (W^2+R^2)^5
\\ + [W^3 R^7] \frac{1}{4} (W+R)^2 (W^2+R^2)^4.$$

From  the first  term  only  $d=1$ contributes,  the  second does  not
contribute at  all and from the  third the first term  must contribute
$WR.$ We get

$$[W^3 R^7] \frac{1}{20} (W+R)^{10}
+ [W^2 R^6] \frac{1}{2} (W^2+R^2)^4
\\ = [W^3 R^7] \frac{1}{20} (W+R)^{10}
+ [W^1 R^3] \frac{1}{2} (W+R)^4.$$

The desired count is thus

$$\frac{1}{20} {10\choose 3} + \frac{1}{2} {4\choose 1}
= 8.$$

Comment: R.Millikans solution is more appealing as it's elegant and swift to slay such an other wise tedious polya enumeration as I predicted 